# SLA for Azure VM for ONLY 1 availibily zone in ONE Region

Tags: azure, microsoft, sla

I'm looking to get the Microsoft SLA for Virtual Machines in Microsoft Azure when there is ONLY 1 availibility zone available in ONE Region.  The following [SLA](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/support/legal/sla/virtual-machines/v1_8/) only describe the SLA when there is a minimum of 2 availability zones.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just use premium storage, you will have a SLA of 99.9 percent:

> For any Single Instance Virtual Machine using premium storage for all
>   Operating System Disks and Data Disks, we guarantee you will have
>   Virtual Machine Connectivity of at least 99.9%.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/virtual-machines/v1_8/